# how many ways can the books be packed?

Tags: combinatorics

Eight diﬀerent books are to be packed in eight diﬀerent bags. If two of the bags are too small to hold ﬁve of the books, in how many ways can the books be packed?

Answer - 4320

My Problem : I can not understand the line "two of the bags are too small to hold ﬁve of the books."

Can anyone make me understand this line?

Comment: I think it means each of those $5$ books are too fat to be put in those boxes

Comment: looks like the problem has a typo but my understanding is that five books are too big for two of the bags/boxes

Comment: I think it means that there are five large books and three small books, and there are two small boxes and six large boxes.

Comment: Yes. Assuming *$1$ book per bag*, there are $5$ books that are individually too big to fit in $2$ of the bags (they are smaller than the other bags). With this interpretation the answer is $4320$.

Comment: Let $x_i$ denote the number of dolls that will be packed in box $i$. Then, you are looking for the number of integer solutions of the equation $$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_7+x_8=8$$ subject to $0\le x_1  + x_2\le 4$ and $0\le x_i$ for $i\ge 3$.                                                                          Is that u r trying to say?@KingTut

Comment: @cmi No they are saying it needs to be packed in $8$ boxes. So as NShales says, thats the only possibility.

Comment: Can u please write ur answer? I do not understand your answer?@N.Shales

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 1 book per bag.

You have $8$ different bags $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ and $8$ different books $\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H\}$.

Each bag can hold at most one book and bags $1$ and $2$ are too small to hold books $A,B,C,D$ and $E$.

This means books $A$ to $E$ can only go in bags $3,4,5,6,7$ and $8$. There are $6!/1!$ ways to place these, each way leaving one empty bag out of those six. Then for each way there are $3!$ ways to place books $F,G$ and $H$ in the remaining three bags (bags $1, 2$ and the empty bag left over from bags $3$ to $8$).

$$\frac{6!}{1!}\cdot 3!=4320\tag{Answer}$$

To illustrate the restrictions of the question check out this table:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
&\text{Bags}\\
\text{Books}& \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 &1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\hline
A&\textbf{X}&\textbf{X}&&&&&&\\\hline
B&\textbf{X}&\textbf{X}&&&&&&\\\hline
C&\textbf{X}&\textbf{X}&&&&&&\\\hline
D&\textbf{X}&\textbf{X}&&&&&&\\\hline
E&\textbf{X}&\textbf{X}&&&&&&\\\hline
F&&&&&&&&\\\hline
G&&&&&&&&\\\hline
H&&&&&&&&\\\hline\end{array}\end{array}$$

Of course, just to reiterate, we must also remember that this is with the additional assumption of 1 book per bag.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "*two of the bags are too small to hold ﬁve of the books*" means probably that you cannot put any of those $5$ books in any of those $2$ bags.

The question also mentions that $8$ books need to be put in $8$ bags, that in turn requires all bags to have exactly one book.

For those two particular bags, we can only put $2$ out of $3$ smaller books available. This is done in $\binom{3}{2}2!$ ways. For the remaining $6$ books we may put them in $6!$ ways in the remaining bags.

So the number of solutions is $\binom{3}{2}\cdot 2!\cdot 6! = 4320$.

Comment: You told  that you cannot put any of those 5 books in any of those 2
bags. Then Why Two Particular bags? I can not understand. No connection between three paras..@King Tut

Comment: Nshales its basically your idea, +1 is deserved by you!

Comment: Can u please write your answer?@N.Shales

Comment: @cmi. It is done. I may add an illustration in a bit. Thanks to King Tut for the lovely comment!